# json object accessing

Tags: json

i know its very simple thing but i m stucked on it

i have json variable with data as follow

```
var jsonText =
 '[ { "user": [ { "Gender": "M", "Minage": "19", "Maxage": "30", "MaritalStatusId":"0",  }] 
    }, 
    { "user":[ { "maritialtype": "Does not matter" }] 
    }, 
    { "user": [ { "Value": "No" }]
    } ]';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonText);
```

now i can access gender as `jsonObject[0].user[0].Gender`

but i'm not able to access `maritialtype` and `Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `maritialtype`:

```
jsonObject[1].user[0].maritialtype
```

For `Value`:

```
jsonObject[2].user[0].Value
```

Because you have an array of three objects, user, which is an array or one object. It's kind of a weird structure.

Comment: yes. got it .. i was trying as jsonObject[1].user[1].maritialtype.. thank you @mike