# Why am I getting a Syntax Error when looping through JSON Objects in an array? How do I extract JSON correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I used an ajax request to GET JSON data from my server-side and I had is sent to my client-side in a response.

I am trying to loop through the array that holds the multiple JSON objects that I need to now store in variables in order to display it in an html table.

As a test I made sure that I could access the JSON data correctly by using:

`console.log("JSON: " + data[0].issue); // this prints the correct data`

As a secondary measure I tested the length of the array before starting a for loop using this:

`console.log("data array length: " + data.length); // this prints the correct array length`

My JSON data is structured as follows:

```
[

{"issueid":"5","username":"Kevin McCluney","issue":"Tables opening & closing when clicked","dateopened":"2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z","type":"Improper Display","priority":"Medium","issuestatus":"Not Started","comments":"When a table is first expanded it appears, disappears, then reappears – that’s distracting; have it appear only once when expanding."},

{"issueid":"4","username":"Kevin McCluney","issue":"Allow users to re-arrange columns \"on the fly\"","dateopened":"2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z","type":"Feature Request","priority":"Low","issuestatus":"Not Started","comments":"It would be nice if the column order could be changed on-the-fly (e.g., by dragging). I consider this low priority. Developer would have to decide if the re-arrangement affects other tables at the same time."},

{"issueid":"3","username":"Kevin McCluney","issue":"Table data display and alignment","dateopened":"2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z","type":"Improper Display","priority":"Medium","issuestatus":"Not Started","comments":"The table data columns need to be aligned in the tables."},

{"issueid":"2","username":"Kevin McCluney","issue":"Additional features open in separate tabs","dateopened":"2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z","type":"Improper Display","priority":"Low","issuestatus":"Not Started","comments":"The documentation and bug tracking features should be opened in new tabs to let the user continue viewing the table data where the user left off."},

{"issueid":"1","username":"Kevin McCluney","issue":"Requesting user login to view Documentation & Bug Database","dateopened":"2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z","type":"Logic Error","priority":"Medium","issuestatus":"Not Started","comments":"The user shouldn't have to login again when opening the documentation or bug tracking features."}

]
```

It seems to me, after having successfully tested the data array by printing them to the console, that all I would need to do is loop through the data array and store each item stored in data with a variable and display it as needed to my table.

However, when I create my for loop as such:

```
// Here i am getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier'
// What gives?????????/
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log("JSON: " + data[i].issueid);
}
```

I get a syntax error like this:

```
'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier'
```

How do I extract the data from the multiple JSON objects correctly???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json object accessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434487/json-object-accessing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` isn't a thing in JavaScript. Use `var` or `let` instead.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log("JSON: " + data[i].issueid);
}
```

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot. This is what I get for going 20 hours straight and working on a project in JS and C++ at the same time. Sorry about that and thank you!!!! As soon as the 12 minute minimum passes I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `int i` to `var i` in the for loop , `int` is not an identifier in javascript

```js
var data = [

  {
    "issueid": "5",
    "username": "Kevin McCluney",
    "issue": "Tables opening & closing when clicked",
    "dateopened": "2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "Improper Display",
    "priority": "Medium",
    "issuestatus": "Not Started",
    "comments": "When a table is first expanded it appears, disappears, then reappears – that’s distracting; have it appear only once when expanding."
  },

  {
    "issueid": "4",
    "username": "Kevin McCluney",
    "issue": "Allow users to re-arrange columns \"on the fly\"",
    "dateopened": "2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "Feature Request",
    "priority": "Low",
    "issuestatus": "Not Started",
    "comments": "It would be nice if the column order could be changed on-the-fly (e.g., by dragging). I consider this low priority. Developer would have to decide if the re-arrangement affects other tables at the same time."
  },

  {
    "issueid": "3",
    "username": "Kevin McCluney",
    "issue": "Table data display and alignment",
    "dateopened": "2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "Improper Display",
    "priority": "Medium",
    "issuestatus": "Not Started",
    "comments": "The table data columns need to be aligned in the tables."
  },

  {
    "issueid": "2",
    "username": "Kevin McCluney",
    "issue": "Additional features open in separate tabs",
    "dateopened": "2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "Improper Display",
    "priority": "Low",
    "issuestatus": "Not Started",
    "comments": "The documentation and bug tracking features should be opened in new tabs to let the user continue viewing the table data where the user left off."
  },

  {
    "issueid": "1",
    "username": "Kevin McCluney",
    "issue": "Requesting user login to view Documentation & Bug Database",
    "dateopened": "2017-08-04T05:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "Logic Error",
    "priority": "Medium",
    "issuestatus": "Not Started",
    "comments": "The user shouldn't have to login again when opening the documentation or bug tracking features."
  }

]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log("JSON: " + data[i].issueid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that in javascript you do not have "int" (in general you do not have type at all!). But only untyped variables. Therefore you should try with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    console.log("JSON: " + data[i].issueid);
}
```